# Bot replies to certain user when saying a certain thing, but the rest of the code doesn't work

Tags: python, discord, bots

My discord bot replies to my friend when they write a discord message including the word 'squippy' with a certain response, and everyone else who doesn't have the user ID gets well, a different response (I'm horrible at explaining so here's the code):

Example of code:
[image: example of code]

And it works great, does everything I want! Only problem is that after I wrote this code, none of my other commands worked. I removed the code and they worked fine. I'm going insane trying to figure out what the problem is. I'll two examples of what code is most primarily well uh, coded before the problem code (?)

Example of code:
[image: example of code]
example of code:
[image: example of code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for other commands to work after the first instance of on_message is used. You need to add `await client.process_commands(message)` at the end of the on_message functions. I assumed that all the commands you linked are in the `on_message` function.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    
    if "squippy" in message.content:
        if message.author.id == USER ID:
            await message.channel.send("Nya Nya I'm your cat boy squip")

        else:
            await message.channel.send("I'm not *your* catboy pet")
    
    if "quantum toaster" in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("Let's get this bread")
    
    if any(word in msg for word in bad_words_2):
        await message.channel.send("Stop")
    

    await client.process_commands(message) # This line would be needed
```